# How to solve trig inequation $|\tan x|\leq \sin 2x$?

Tags: trigonometry

> How to solve trig inequation $|\tan x|\leq \sin 2x$? Given that $x \in [0,\pi]$

I'm not sure how to solve this inequation.
My lecturer gave me only 2 pages on trig, and it is very hard for me.
Anyone's help? :(

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, we need $$\dfrac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}=\sin2x\ge0\iff\tan x\ge0$$

In that case $|\tan x|=+\tan x$

$$\implies\sin2x-|\tan x|=\dfrac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}-\tan x=\tan x\left(\dfrac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}\right)$$

$$\sin2x-|\tan x|\ge0\iff1-\tan^2x\ge0\iff-1\le\tan x\le1$$

But we have $\tan x\ge0,$ so we need $$0\le\tan x\le1$$

$$\iff n\pi\le x\le n\pi+\dfrac\pi4$$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Thank you, I have only one question. Why it is clear that tanx≥0?

Comment: @Sam.Z, As $1+\tan^2x\ge1>0$

Answer (score 1):

By the sine duplication formula

$$|\tan x|\leq \sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x.$$

If $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, then $\tan x \geq 0$ thus

$$\tan x \leq 2 \sin x \cos x$$

Applying the definition of tangent

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \leq 2 \sin x \cos x$$

it yields to

$$\frac{1}{2} \leq \cos^2 x.$$

Since the cosine is positive in the considered interval

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \leq cos x \Rightarrow x \leq \arccos \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

the second inequality needs to be switched, because $\arccos x$ is a decreasing function.

Therefore $$x\in \big [0,\frac{\pi}{4} \big ].$$

Comment: This will not give all the solutions. but nice. you forgot that the function is periodic with period $\pi$.

Comment: Of course it does not give all the solutions, in fact I restricted the domain just in order to give a possible path for the solution. Give the complete solution was not my purpose.

Comment: @Dante, What if $x=\dfrac\pi3?$

Comment: You are right, $\arccos x$ is a decreasing function.

Answer (score 0):

let $f(x)=|\tan(x)|-\sin(2x)$ first find all zeros. That is to see where $sin(x)$ and $sin(2x)$ both are zero which is $k\pi$'s for $k=\cdots,-1,0,1,\cdots$ or where $\cos(x)=1/\sqrt{2}$ by comparison of the signs the result is $k\pi+\pi/4$. Now the result is $k\pi\leq x\leq k\pi+\pi/4$.